# I'm can't quite wrap my head around this code for checking for a perfect square

Tags: c++, number-theory

I'm a novice as may be obvious, in advanced c++ at my school and I was working on home work and was having issues with try to figure out how to decide if an integer is a perfect square or not when I stumbled across this piece of code.

```
if (num <= 0 || sqrt(num) != static_cast<int>(sqrt(num)))
      throw "Error: The number is not a perfect square.\n";

    return sqrt(num);
```

If possible  as an exception function I just don't quite understand how the piece after || works. And would just like to know for future reference.

Comment: `static_cast<int>(sqrt(num))` is a way to write "floor of square root of `num`" Hope this helps.

Comment: Take a piece of paper and a pencil. Now pick a number, and plug it into the formula, and see what happens. Try both random numbers, and numbers which are "perfect squares", such as 36 or 49. It shouldn't take long before you figure out your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

This last part checks if the number is an integer.

`sqrt(num)` will return a number that might have a decimal, and `static_cast<int>(sqrt(num)))` will return an integer.

If the number has a decimal,
`static_cast<int>(sqrt(num)))` will take the decimal out. If the casted value was for example

`4.32`

the static cast would take out the decimal and return

`4`

The if statement checks if the square root of the number is the same as the version  with the decimal taken out

If the square root does not equal the square root with the decimal taken out, then it isn't a perfect square

With the number 4.32 as example again

`if( sqrt(num) != static_cast<int>(sqrt(num)) )`

would be turned into

`if( 4.32 != static_cast<int>(4.32))`

which would be turned into

`if(4.32 != 4)`

Comment: Thank you very much for that. I also should have pointed out that when it comes to some math stuff I'm a bit rusty but trying to get myself back to a good point with it. This explanation made perfect sense and I can completely see it now.thank you for helping me understand.

Answer (score 1):

sqrt(num) returns the square root as a floating point number.  static_cast will attempt to convert the return value to an integer, which will be successful and truncate the value to an integer.  If num was a perfect square, this won't do anything and the values will be equal.